# Using NSPredicate's `array[FIRST]` operator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I see in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891) there's an `array[FIRST]` operator, which is exactly what I need to write the predicate I want. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't provide any examples and I don't see how I can clearly put that in a predicate.

So, for instance, I'd have something like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"array[FIRST] IN %@", @[@1, @2, @3]`. This, of course, throws an exception:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x100001058> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key array.'`

Because this predicate will eventually go in a core data model file, I need to represent this in a stringly format, so any solutions involving code won't work.

Comment: The error indicates that the predicate is being evaluated against a string, not a CoreData managed object.  Can you give more detail of the model and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @pbasdf I understand the error. That's not my question. The question is how to correctly extract the first element out of the array given a predicate. Core Data is incidental to this problem.

Comment: Which array are you trying to extract elements from?  An array of managed objects?

Comment: That's right. It's going to be a fetched property on an entity in an xcdatamodel file.

Comment: OK.  So you want your fetched property to be "the first object that matches this predicate"?  If so, I don't think it can be done: a) fetched properties always return an array (even if only one object matches), and b) the model editor will not let you specify a sort order for the FP, so you are taking pot luck as to which matching object is the first.

Comment: Interesting! Ordering was not something that I'd anticipated. Would a computed property on the object work? The object holds a reference to the other managed object to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate needs to make sense after substituting the `%@` values in the format string and substituting `SELF` with the object being evaluated.  Your predicate says: "is the first object in an *unknown symbol called 'array'* contained within the literal array 1,2,3?"

Consider the following examples...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[FIRST] == %@", @1];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@[@1, @2, @3]];
// result will be YES

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[FIRST] == %@", @2];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@[@1, @2, @3]];
// result will be NO

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@[FIRST] == SELF", @[@1, @2, @3]];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@1];
// result will be YES

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@[FIRST] == SELF", @[@1, @2, @3]];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:@2];
// result will be NO
```